# store different enum types in enumSet

Tags: java, enums, enumset

I want to store different enum types within one enum.

**Is this the right (shortest) way?**

```
public enum MyEnums {
    all(EnumSet.of(Color.red, Shape.round));

    MyEnums(EnumSet<? extends Enum<?>> keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    private final Set<? extends Enum<?>> keys;

    public Set<? extends Enum<?>> getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use another type of set.

Comment: why? I guess, enumsets are right here..

Comment: EnumSet is designed to hold enum values of a single kind only. The point is that it is very efficient because it stores a bit mask of the present ordinal values. If you have multiple enum types, it can't distinguish values from different enums with the same ordinal.

Comment: Ohh, did not notice that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different kind of set. EnumSet is [designed to hold enum values of a single kind only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

> All of the elements in an enum set must come from a single enum type

The point is that it is very efficient because it stores a bit mask of the present ordinal values - most enums have fewer than 64 values, so all it basically needs in terms of member variables is the `Class` and a `long`. (There is a private subclass of EnumSet called something like JumboEnumSet which handles larger enums).

If you have multiple enum types, it can't distinguish values from different enums with the same ordinal.